# Conditionnal function where condition is on argument

Tags: python, function, if-statement

Here my problem :

Assumming two database :

```
normalized_product_matrix = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), index = ['43','44'], columns = ['1','2'])

normalized_user_matrix = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 3], [2, 4]]), index = ['1','2'], columns = ['43','44'])
```

I would like to create a function where the condition "if" hold on the different values that the parameter can take (the values being one of the names of the two database).

Here an exemple i coded :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def user_local_trust_computation (norm_matrix) :
            
    product_matrix_indicator = 'normalized_product_matrix'
    user_matrix_indicator = 'normalized_user_matrix'
    
    if norm_matrix == product_matrix_indicator :
    
        multiIndex = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([np.repeat(np.array(norm_matrix.index, dtype = np.uint32), len(norm_matrix.index)), np.tile(np.array(norm_matrix.index, dtype = np.uint32).reshape(len(norm_matrix.index),1),(len(norm_matrix.index),1)).flatten()], names = ('Wine_I','Wine_J'))
            
    elif norm_matrix == user_matrix_indicator :
    
        multiIndex = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([np.repeat(np.array(norm_matrix.index, dtype = np.uint32), len(norm_matrix.index)), np.tile(np.array(norm_matrix.index, dtype = np.uint32).reshape(len(norm_matrix.index),1),(len(norm_matrix.index),1)).flatten()], names = ('User_U','User_V'))
            
    else : 
        
        multiIndex = 1
    
    return multiIndex
```

But when i call my function with :

```
user_local_trust_computation (normalized_product_matrix)
```

Its return 1 for my multiIndex. So it's seems that my equality test doesn't work.

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work, maybe the way you called the function it is incorrect.

```
def user_local_trust_computation(norm_matrix) :
            
    product_matrix_indicator = 'normalized_product_matrix'
    user_matrix_indicator = 'normalized_user_matrix'
    
    if norm_matrix == product_matrix_indicator :
        multiIndex = -1
    elif norm_matrix == user_matrix_indicator :
        multiIndex = 0
    else : 
        multiIndex = 1
    return multiIndex

print(user_local_trust_computation("normalized_product_matrix"))  # -1
print(user_local_trust_computation("normalized_user_matrix"))  # 0
print(user_local_trust_computation("smth"))  # 1
```

Comment: Thanks :).

Indeed it's works the way you wrote it, but this way i can't define my multiIndex, since i can't call, for example, the index of the database in argument : norm_matrix.index.